# Error de formato RFC2822 con fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy haciendo un calendario de eventos con fullcalendar. Estoy tratando de mediante un botón, agregar un evento a  mi calendario, pero a la hora de hacerlo me aparece el siguiente error en la consola.

[image: Imagen de la consola]

El trozo de código que se ejecuta es el siguiente.

```html
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'today,prev,next,Miboton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek, basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          customButtons: {
            Miboton: {
              text: "Botón 1",
              click: function() {
                alert("Accion del boton");
              }
            }
          },
          dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            $('#txtFecha').val(date.format());
            $("#ModalEventos").modal();
          },

          eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            $('#tituloEvento').html(calEvent.title);
            $('#descripcionEvento').html(calEvent.descripcion);

            $("#exampleModal").modal();
          }
        });

      });

    </script>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="tituloEvento"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="descripcionEvento"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dafult">cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal(Agregar, modificar, eliminar) -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEventos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="tituloEvento"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="descripcionEvento"></div>
            Fecha: <input type="text" id="txtFecha" name="txtFecha" /><br/> 
            Título: <input type="text" id="txtTitutlo"><br/> 
            Hora: <input type="text" id="txtHora" value="10:30" /><br/> 
            Descripcion: <textarea id="txtDescripcion" rows="3"></textarea><br/>            
            Color: <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="txtColor"><br/>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnAgregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Modificar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dafult">cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      $('#btnAgregar').click(function() {

        var NuevoEvento = {
          title: $('#txtTitulo').val(),
          start: $('#txtFecha').val() + " " + $('txtHora').val(),
          color: $('#txtColor').val(),
          descripcion: $('#txtDescripcion').val(),
          textColor: "#FFFFFF"

        };
        $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('renderEvent', NuevoEvento);
        $("#ModalEventos").modal('toggle');
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: En el código que has pasado, no hay php, modifica las etiquetas de la pregunta y coloca javascript y jquery :)

Comment: El formato que estas dando a la fecha **start** es incorrecta y no cumple los nuevos requerimientos del calendario de usar el formato ISO8601String. Usa las funciones del modulo jquery momentjs, que utiliza también el fullCalendar internamente para la gestión de la fecha. Aquí tienes mas información para tu caso concreto, en la sección para los parámetros **start** y **end** de cada evento: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: Otra cosa que puede ayudarte, es utilizar la opcion **locale** para que moments y fullCalendar trabajen con formatos de fechas mas completos, complejos y personalizados a un idioma concreto (o varios). Te dejo El enlace también. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale